# Can I implement this somehow without using the new keyword? C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, new-operator

Is there a way I can implement this without using the `new` keyword?

```
void World::generateChunk(Coordinate coord) {
    if(loadedChunks[coord])
        delete loadedChunks[coord];
    loadedChunks[coord] = new Chunk(coord);
    loadedChunks[coord]->generate();
}
```

loadedChunks is a `std::map<Coordinate, Chunk*>`.

Comment: Without a definition of what `loadedChunks` is this question cannot be answered.

Comment: I added that right before you asked. :P @DavidRodríguez-dribeas

Comment: `*loadedChunks[coord] = Chunk(coord);` might work, if `Chunk` is copyable.

Comment: If `Coordinate` is not heavyweight to copy just use `std::vector<Coordinate>`

Comment: If Chunk is implemented with Move semantics, than you should just use std::map<Coordinate,Chunk> and call it a day.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams The problem with that is that multiple maps might point at that chunk.

Comment: @Binero You are in trouble then, because you just `delete`d it.

Comment: @Casey The destructor knows where to look. :P

Comment: @Binero If you need `Chunk` to be referred to by multiple things, make `loadedChunks` a `std::map<Coordinate, std::shared_ptr<Chunk>>`.

Comment: @Casey sounds like a good time for a std::shared_ptr<Chunk>, which will take care of all the reference counting on whether or not there are multiple pointers to that one chunk.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you trying to avoid memory allocation with `new`?

Comment: @NikosC. Because that means I need to delete it too, and I know I will probably forget that somewhere. :P

Comment: @Binero You should look into smart pointers. `std::auto_ptr` is *not* suitable for this, but C++11 provides smart pointers that can be used, as does Boost. For example `std::map<Coordinate, std::shared_ptr<Chunk>>`. Do a bit of research on the net on how to use smart pointers. Here's a nice article: http://www.drdobbs.com/collecting-shared-objects/184401839

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, by using a:

```
std::map<Coordinate, Chunk>
```

World::generateChunk() would them become:

```
void World::generateChunk(Coordinate coord)
{
    loadedChunks[coord] = Chunk(coord);
    loadedChunks[coord].generate();
}
```

Be aware of the implications of this. There's no destructor call anymore since the existing object is being assigned to. And polymorphism doesn't work anymore (you won't be able to store `Chunk` subclasses in `loadedChunks`.) Furthermore, at least `loadedChunks.size()` objects will always exist; they are not deletable.

`Chunk` must also meet the criteria of the standard container classes, like being copy-constructible, assignable, etc. And make sure that those operations work correctly (for example you need to determine whether you need a deep copy or shallow copy.)

Comment: … and by writing a proper constructor we’d get rid of the horrible, horrible `generate` method (why is it horrible? Because it’s doing the constructor’s job!). Small typo though: replace `->` by `.`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Not necessarily all chunks will be generated.

Comment: @Binero they will only be created in the map when referenced.

Comment: @Binero Then you’re stuck with half-initialised objects which is usually a situation that you want to avoid at all cost. Without knowing your specific use case: how about removing those non-generated chunks from the map instead?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Chunks don't necessarily are part of a world. They can also be used as a list of items and objects, which they basically are. The generate function just fills it with the default objects.

Comment: @Binero Like I said it’s hard to judge without having more specifics about your particular scenario but I’d still say that this sounds like a design weakness. First of all, because they sound like “god objects” which fulfil more than one purpose. And secondly, because filling them with default objects can well be done by the constructor. Remember that constructors can be overloaded to do different things.

Comment: @KonradRudolph They are what they are. Chunks. What if you copy a chunk? What if I link 2 chunks so all edits on one chunk will represent on the other? It wouldn't be part of the world, but it'd still be a chunk in the memory. I would be able to use it as a chunk.

Comment: @Binero Well, what’s a “chunk” in your context? “Chunk” is an extremely general term. And I don’t understand your questions.

Comment: @KonradRudolph A chunk is an object representing a list of blocks. A world can use these "chunks" to know how to display itself. A world can point to the same chunk for different coordinates. A chunk can also be used outside the world like for example when copying it. They are like IP addresses you can connect to to get data. Multiple members can use them, some IP Addresses point to the same servers.

Comment: @Binero Ah. So that does indeed sound like your design may be appropriate. :)

Comment: @Binero You're rewriting Minecraft in C++? :-P

Comment: @NikosC. It's not even sandbox so I wouldn't say that. But yeah it is based on it.